# Axis label in tikzpicture is shifted

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why the x axis label not in the right position

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
     \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}          
     
     \pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
\begin{axis}[
     xlabel={$t$(ms)},
     grid=both,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
     ylabel={$v(t)$},
     axis lines=left,
    scaled ticks=false,
    width=15cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    minor tick num=4,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.2},
    xmin = 0, xmax = 2,
    ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
    ytick={-1,1},
    yticklabels={$-100$,$100$},
    xtick= { 0.3333, 0.8333 ,1.3333 ,1.8333 ,2.3333},
    xticklabels={5.5556 ,13.8889 ,22.2222 ,30.5556, 38.8889},
     x tick label style={font=\small, rotate=0,below}                        
            ]

     \addplot[domain=0:2,samples=50,smooth,black, ultra thick] {cos(deg(2*pi*x-(2*pi/3)))};

\end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is *right* position?

Comment: please update your pgfplots and use `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` in the meantime.

Comment: the right position is near the axis not in the middle of the figure. but I found out its because I used scale=0.25, but the axis label should adjust

Comment: \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} solved the problem

Comment: better choose something explicit. E. g. `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` should work. I do not know, which version you have installed or can install.

Comment: You have two `axis lines=` (considered is the last: `left`. Is this ok? Delete the one, which you not like to have.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved with upgrade of the used `pgfplots` package.

Answer (score 1):

A minimum of `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` is needed for this to work.
You can always use `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` but an explicite declaration should be preferred imho.
Please make sure to update pgfplots and all your other packages, if you really are still on pgfplots 1.5